# Visual Studio 2015 RC & Cordova: Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

**Environment**

- VS 14.0.22823.1 D14REL
- jdk1.7.0_55 32 bit which comes with current Android SDK
- Windows 8.1

**Problem:**

- Create new Project of type "Appache Cordova Apps", leave default name "BlankCordovApp3"
- Build the app with default settings: Works fine
- Doubleclick config.xml; the config editor opens; goto "platforms" and change Cordova CLI to "5.0.0."
- Rebuild solution it several times and/or select "Clean Solution"
- Error message: "Error occurred during initialization of VM;  ***Could not reserve enough space for object heap***"

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

- Do not change any JVM arguments, there is a reason for the Cordova scripts to use those settings of minimum an maximum heap size.
- In my case: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`
- Instead, use a 64 bit JDK and either set it to the PATH environment variable (Control Panel => Environment Variables) or in VS goto "Tools => Options => Tools for Apache Cordova => Environment Variable Overrides"
- Clean and/or rebuild solution
- Solved the problem for me
- Don't know what the exact problem is. I'm new to Cordova. Could be a size limitation of a 32 bit JVM on Windows 8.1 or the daemon process which does not correctly free memory after several runs.

Comment: The suggested "Environment Variable Overrides" setting worked for me.