# cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2015. I just created new project Installed>JavaScript>Blank App(Apache Cordova). I have selected Android>Google-Android-Emulator platform. when i click on Google-Android-Emulator it gives this error "**cmd: Command failed with exit code 2**". i already searched a lot but non of the solution works for me.

Here is my output window result

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp7, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.4 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.0
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 4.3.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp7
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins:
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Preparing android project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins: []
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "BlankCordovaApp7"
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myapp236d7e"
1>  ------ Copied C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug""
1>  Command finished with error code 2: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\Muzafar Khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug"
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I tried the same thing, but the build file ended differently. Your line (before the error is found) ends in .....cordova\build.bat" --debug" but mine has ....cordova\build.bat" --debug --ant "". So maybe your android SDK didn't install correctly. Have you tried running the Ripple emulator instead, it needs less prerequisites setting up.

Comment: Ripple emulator work fine

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue ! I thought that space character might be a problem in the path but no change. My logs :

`1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c "c:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=c:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json""
1>  Command finished with error code 2: cmd /s /c "c:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=c:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json"
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2`

What is weird is that when I launch manually on a cmd window

`c:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=c:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json`

, it works well and my apk is created in the debug directory, so I'd say that maybe the problem comes from "/s /c . It just seems that the command simply cannot be executed, but I'm stuck here...

**EDIT & Solution :** I now have more informations. It seems it's due to a lack of heap memory : Go to Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> Build and Run, change MSBuild project build output verbosity to Diagnostic. Rebuild the project and post the text from output window.
I have

`Error occurred during initialization of VM (TaskId:11)
1>  Could not reserve enough space for object heap (TaskId:11)`

Check if you do not have the same.  If yes, problem is simply resolved by installing a 64bit version of java (to know if yours is 64b, simply try java -d64 -version).
In fact, this problem has already been resolved here : 
[Visual Studio 2015 RC & Cordova: Could not reserve enough space for object heap (solved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827160/visual-studio-2015-rc-cordova-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

All you have to do is : 
-Install a 64b version of Java if you haven't.
- Override the java home path in VS/Tools/Options/Tools for Apache Cordova / Environnement variable Overrides / JAVA HOME.
For example, it's is now C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51 for me.
(carefull not to point to Program Files (x86) )

It works for me.

To go further, you might want have a look at this page explaining how to configure your real android device for debug : http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/

You might have to install proper usb drive for your phone, google generic one does not work for everyone. That's it !

Answer (score 0):

Setting up PATHs for cordova doesn't work with Environment variables.
In Visual Studio (2013 or higher) you have to go to **Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova**, and setup android sdk path from there.
I've dealt with this error and found out that there's a **Dependency Checker** that tells you about all the things you need to run your code.