# build apk error in cordova visual studio

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I want to release **apk** file with **cordova in visual studio 2015**
I built the build.json file with my created key, but the problem is not solved.
I have 2 errors:

- Command failed with exit code 2: ERROR building one of the platforms
- Command failed with exit code 2: MDAVSCLI

I read all of previous Q&A about this issue but none of them solved the problem

[image]

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629369/cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-2     Regardless, please post the output window results too - they often have more verbose error logging.

Comment: I checked that but there was not any clear answer for my problem.
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with help of microsoft Senior Program Manager of Cordova [Mr. Minguez](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ricardo-minguez-pablos-a61183)

Afte checking the output logs, I had this line containing the error description:

[Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.

I had 2-3 different jdk installed on my PC. Uninstalled them all and start to install the jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe and changed my JAVA_Home to newly installed jdk folder.
After restart my project compiled successfully.